# Use service variable's from controller

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I have a problem with my app using ionic. In my Service.js I have a function that retrieve my position and in my controller.js I have the function that when I press a button in my html page, send the user in another page. So, when I press a button, before the app send me to another page, I would like that start the function in my service.js(geolocation), and send me only if the geolocation is success.

How can I do that?

I thought that I can save a variable on service.js. If the function enter onSuccess, I save variable = 1, if the function enter on error, I save variable = 0. But I don't know how use this variable on my controller...

service.js :

```
.factory('position', function() {
    return{
    positioning : function(){
    var geocoder;
     geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  initialise = function() {

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy : true, timeout : 5000, maximumAge : 0}); 
    function onSuccess(position){


      myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);  
    }
    function onError(error){
      alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n'); 
      cordova.plugins.settings.openSetting("open", function(){console.log("opened settings")},function(){console.log("failed to open nfc settings")});  
    } 

  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialise());
```

Controller.js:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$state, position) {
  $scope.mappa=function(){
      $state.go('tab.mappa');
    position.positioning();

  }
  $scope.dettagli=function(){
    $state.go('tab.dettagli');
    position.positioning();
  }
  $scope.strada=function(){
    $state.go('tab.strada');
    position.positioning();
  }
  $scope.segnalazioni=function(){
    $state.go('tab.segnalazioni');
    position.positioning();
  }
  $scope.SOS=function(){
    $state.go('tab.sos');
    position.positioning();
  }
```

html page :

```
<ion-view view-title="Home" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <div >
    <!-- LA MIA POSIZIONE -->
        <div class="max-width width-forty">
            <button class="button button-full button-royal" ng-click="mappa()">
                <table>
                <tr><td><i class="fa fa-map fa-hx fa-inverse"></i></td></tr>
                <tr><td class="button-text-map-sos">La mia posizione</td></tr>
                </table>
            </button>
            </div>
.........
..........
.........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your configuration module when you are using ui-router, you can check for the location using a service that returns a promise and view the map if you have the location or display an error if not.

```
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'page1.html',
        controller: 'page1Ctrl'
      })
      .state('map-view', {
        url: '/map-view/:forceBad',
        templateUrl: 'page2.html',
        controller: 'page2Ctrl',
        resolve: {
          location: function(GeoLocation, $q, $stateParams) {
            return GeoLocation.getLocation($stateParams.forceBad)
              .then(function(_response) {
                return _response;
              }, function(_error) {
                alert('error getting location')
                return $q.reject("no location found");
              });
          }
        }
      });
  })
```

In the sample controller we pass a flag to force a bad or good location so you can see both paths in the application routing

```
  .controller('page1Ctrl', function($scope, $state) {
  // click a button either force bad result or get good result
    $scope.clicked = function(_forceBad) {
      alert('clicked with forceBad ' + _forceBad);
      $state.go('map-view', {
        forceBad: _forceBad
      });
    }
  })
```

In the service we return an error when `forceBad` is set to `true`

```
  .service('GeoLocation', function($state, $q) {
    return {
      /**
      * when passed true, the service will not return a location
      */
      getLocation: function(_forceBad) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        setTimeout(function() {

          if (_forceBad === "true") {
            return deferred.reject({
              type: 'error',
            });
          }
          return deferred.resolve({
            type: 'location',
            lat: 100,
            lng: -100
          })
        }, 200);
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    }
  })
```

[See complete codePen Here](http://codepen.io/aaronksaunders/pen/NGqpgL)

Answer (score 0):

The main issue seems to be the fact that you are not injecting your `position` factory into your `MainCtrl` controller.

Please read a bit about dependency injection in Angular:

- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Dependency-Injection
- https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

**Edit after comments:**

Ok, I think I understand your problem a bit better.
The good and clean way to do what you want is to use [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).
Your `positioning` function should return a promise. This way, your controller will know if the location has been found or not.

The `$cordovaGeolocation` factory from [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/) should help you to do this (see the example for `getCurrentPosition`).

[This tutorial](http://www.joshmorony.com/integrating-google-maps-with-an-ionic-application/) could help you thanks to the "*Create a Map in Your Application*" part.

Comment: EExcuse me, I have change some code, because I dd some text before post the question, I injecting position in my controller.                                              position.positioning() works well, but when gps is disable and the function enter in onError, the app send me in the next page, but this have to do only if the function is onSuccess

Comment: Can you write an example with promises?